# How might greedy ever be a synonym of parsimonious?

Tags: synonyms, antonyms, semantics

thesaurus.com puts 'avaricious' at the top of its list of synonyms for 'parsimonious', and 'greedy' a little further down. To my mind, an essential sense of parsimony is self-denial.

The only way I can imagine 'greedy' as a synonym would be via the idea that lack of generosity to others might be accompanied by self-interest. I think 'stingy' could be used to describe this pair of traits. But surely 'parsimonious' implies frugality in general, and 'greedy' would be more an antonym than a synonym?

Comment: I agree with you. thesaurus.com looks like computer-generated garbage to me.

Comment: For a question like this with "ever" in it: the answer is surely "yes".  Merely being unable to think of an instance of it does not mean it can never happen.

Comment: @GEdgar That's easily rectified. The answer isn't "Yes" now.

Comment: @AndrewLeach ... Correct.  Generally, a "How" question cannot be answered yes/no.

Answer (score 1):

I searched with Google for

> "parsimonoious algorithm" greedy

I found many examples in mathematics and computer science where an algorithm is called both "parsimonious" and "greedy".

For example, the text *Discrete Mathematics with Ducks*
by sarah-marie belcastro.  There is an exercise on page 374:

> (a) Design a greedy (parsimonious) algorithm for coloring the vertices of a graph...

Comment: Calling an algorithm both parsimonious and greedy sounds like the words are explicitly NOT being used synonymously, although your quote from Belcastro is more ambiguous.

Comment: Here's a "definition" saying [*parsimonious algorithms **eliminate or reduce** the demands of parameter-tuning experiments.*](https://uwspace.uwaterloo.ca/bitstream/handle/10012/7133/Asadzadeh_Masoud.pdf?sequence=1) And [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm) says *a greedy algorithm is any algorithm that follows the problem-solving heuristic of making the **locally optimal choice** at each stage.* I don't have a big problem with seeing those two definitions as "overlapping" or even somewhat "synonymous". They're certainly not exactly "opposite" - or even "orthogonal".

Comment: Quoted from Discrete Mathematics with Ducks: "...such algorithms are called greedy because they grab the best thing available at every stage. (For problems whose goal is to minimize something, this name doesn’t make intuitive sense; it seems that in these cases the algorithms are parsimonious instead because they are grabbing the least stuff possible.) Most of the time, a greedy/parsimonious algorithm works pretty well. " Greedy here means grabbing whatever is available locally but discarding it just as rapidly, in order to remain parsimonious.

Answer (score 0):

"Greedy" is used more widely than in the context of food. In a more general context it describes a person who acquires everything that he can. The most famous example I can think of who is both parsimonious and greedy, is Ebenezer Scrooge.

Comment: Thank you for trying to answer. But my original point was that you would use a different word to describe Scrooge-type people, not parsimonious. Indeed, to you it is only a "famous example" in hindsight, now that you have read the question and believe that Scrooge could have been described as parsimonious. But it's hardly a famous example, because the root *parsimon-* does not appear at all in [Christmas Carol](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/19337/19337-h/19337-h.htm) (I just checked).

Answer (score 0):

- Words have multiple distinct meanings. It is rare to look in a dictionary for a word and find a single meaning. For example, [the seemingly uncomplicated  'dog'](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dog) has many.
- Words, or one distinct meaning of one word, have multiple associations. FOr example,

> #8 one inferior of its kind "the movie was a dog"

It could refer to the amount of money it earned, poor reviews by critics, or the speaker just didn't like it. While correlated, these are not identical.

- There are no exact synonyms. Synonyms are not usually one-to-one or replaceable one with the other everywhere. One synonym is usually better than another. Synonyms usually are considered to have mostly the same meaning, but they can't always overlap in every facet.

The primary meaning of 'parsimonious' is 'as simple as possible'. The primary meaning of 'greedy' is 'desiring and pulling in wealth'. These seem orthogonal. But both words have implications of reducing *need* for resources. 'Greedy' also has the connotation of choosing quickly with little extra thought (which is often the case when one is trying to rake in money quickly). This leads to the idea of making quick simple choices and that is the overlap. Stinginess in making choices is parsimonious and greedy.

Thesaurus.com creates its lists automatically by calculating on huge amounts of text and seeing where different words appear in similar contexts. So in some sense it is semantically blind and just sees the numbers. And by that 'parsimonious' and 'greedy' statistically just happen to similar contexts.

But semantically, someone who is miserly is usually parsimonious and likewise greedy, so they are associated that way. If you're greedy, not only will you try to gain a lot of money, but you will also try to spend very little of it, which is one kind of parsimony.